# Can't retrieve data from Firebase Angular2

Tags: html, firebase, angularfire2

Method in firebase.service.ts to retrieve data

```
getListingDetails(id){
this.listing = this.af.database.object('records/listings/'+id) as FirebaseObjectObservable<Listing>
return this.listing;
}
```

code in listing.component.html to display retrieved data

```
    <div ng-if="listing">
    <a [routerLink]="['/listings']">Go Back</a>
    <br>
    <h2 class="page-header">{{listing.title}} <small>{{listing.city}}</small></h2>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <!--IMAGE HERE -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">Owner: {{listing.owner}}</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Bedrooms: {{listing.bedrooms}}</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Type: {{listing.type}}</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Price: {{listing.price}}</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Edit</a>
  <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Error showing in the browser console

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
   at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///AppModule/ListingComponent.ngfactory.js:188:31)
```

at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer]

But after those errors the object is retrieved but not displayed in the html tags

```
Object {bedrooms: 15, city: "San Francisco", image: "mansion1.jpg", owner:   "Bruce Springstien", path: "/img/mansion1.jpg"…}
```

Comment: Check the error message. It clearly stats that 'title' is not there. And even in your object you can clearly see that its not available. Check from Firebase side. May be you are missing `title` over there. Or may be you have not retrieved in your api.

Comment: but it's there, here is the expanded object,                                          Object
$exists
:
()
$key
:
"-Kdl_wRRkn7nJxgz4B54"
bedrooms
:
15
city
:
"San Francisco"
image
:
"mansion1.jpg"
owner
:
"Bruce Springstien"
path
:
"/img/mansion1.jpg"
price
:
"10m"
title
:
"15 Bedroom Mansion"
type
:
"Estate"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: As you can see title is there but I dont know why that error is occuring,

Comment: Then check for API which you have created. You must have missed title.

Comment: Title is there in the API

Comment: Remove title and check whether you are getting rest of the bindings correct or not .

Comment: Nop, I don't get the rest

Comment: May be you are binding with wrong object. Check that

Comment: It doesn't say that title is missing, it says `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`. The error is the variable `listing`, not the property `title`.

Comment: @Pharaoh can you please explain me what is wrong there?

Comment: I don't know firebase, nor angularfire2. The error makes me assume you haven't passed `listing` correctly, but the part of the code seems to be missing here.

Answer (score 0):

```
yours: <li class="list-group-item">Owner: {{listing.owner}}</li>

Answer: <li class="list-group-item">Owner: {{listing?.owner}}</li>
```

? wildcard checks and resolves your issue